# ブラウザの動作環境の判定

Tags: python, http, jsp

あるサービスにプログラム上からPythonでログインしたいと思っています。
しかし、「動作環境が対象外です」というページに飛ばされてしまいます。
User-Agentを偽装しても同じようなことが起こってしまいます。
User-Agent以外で環境を判定しているような箇所はないのでしょうか?
必要な情報は全て、POSTで送っています。
ちなみにリクエストを送る先は.jspファイルです。
送っているデータはUserid, passwordでUserIdは8桁の数字、passwordは8文字の英数字です。
ちなみにこのサービスの実装がどうなっているのか、私はわかりません。
Statusは200  OKを返しています。

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

post_data = {"UserId": 12345678, "Password": "password"}
encoded_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data).encode()
req = urllib.request.Request("http://example.com/login", 
                             encoded_data,
                             headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"})
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
res_read = res.read().decode("shift-jis") # res_readに"動作環境が対象外です"の文字が含まれています。
```

必要な動作環境は以下の通りです。

Windows Vista SP2以上     
・Internet Explorer 7
・Internet Explorer 8
・Internet Explorer 9
・Google Chrome

Windows 7   
・Internet Explorer 8
・Internet Explorer 9
・Internet Explorer 10
・Internet Explorer 11
・Google Chrome

Windows 8 (デスクトップUI)    
・Internet Explorer 10

Windows 8.1 (デスクトップUI)  
・Internet Explorer 11

Mac OS X 10.6   
・Safari 5.1.7

Mac OS X 10.7 
・Safari 5.1.7

Comment: 必要な動作環境は何ですか？弾かれてる理由は分かりませんか？ブラウザを用いたウェブアプリケーションであれば、ログイン時にクライアントに投げている情報を開発ツール(ブラウザでF12押下)で確認できると思いますが、所望の情報がサーバーに投げられていますか？

Comment: 必要な環境について追記しました。

Comment: 実際のコードに近いものを追加しました。

Comment: エラーに動作環境のことが書かれているからといって、動作環境に関する要素で判断したとは限りませんよね。となると**HTTPリクエスト内のどこか**が原因だろうとなりますが、それは「ブラウザなどで正常に動くときのリクエスト内容」と比較しないとわかりません。故に、豚吐露さんが書かれたようにそれをご自身で確認していただくか、具体的なURLを提示していただかないと、答えようがないです。

Comment: まずHTTPレスポンスヘッダを確認してください。大抵の場合はそこに原因が記載されています。

Comment: @pgrho APIというわけでもないようですし、せいぜい403になっている程度で、めぼしい情報は記載されていないのでは・・・。ログイン画面のようなので何かしらトークンが不足してる気はしますが。

Comment: @unarist 個人的にはリダイレクト絡みを疑っています。

Comment: WireSharkなどのパケットキャプチャツールを使って、実際のRequest/Responseを取得し、プログラム側でそれを偽装するように設計すればいいのではないかと思います。
ブラウザのRequest/Responseだけ見たいならば、JMeterでも可能ですし。

Comment: そのサービスの管理者に必要な情報を問い合わせてください。
正規にプログラムからの使用許可を取っているのであれば、
アクセスに必要な情報を教えてくれるでしょう。
逆に許可を取れないサービスであるならできるだけ避けるべきと考えます。
自己判断で行う場合、大きな責任が降り掛かってくることも有りえます。
理由は、公のサービスでは規約上で不正アクセスに該当している可能性があるからです。
もっともサンプルを見る限りは、SSLを使ってないので公のサービスでは無さそうですが。

Answer (score 2):

> User-Agent以外で環境を判定しているような箇所はないのでしょうか?

ブラウザやOSを判別したい**だけ**ならUAで事足りることも多いですが、それだけを理由に「動作環境が対象外です」というエラーが表示されるとは限りません。

ですから、エラーが出る原因となる箇所は**いくらでも考えられます**。また、これまでに質問者さんが提示している情報では、それが具体的に何かまではわかりません。

### どうやって調べるか

どのように実装されているかわからない以上、あなたがブラウザを操作してログインできた、という時に行われた通信が一番の参考資料になります。これを各種ツールで覗き見ることになるでしょう。

- ブラウザのデバッグ機能（Chromeでいえば開発者ツールのNetworkタブ）
- Fiddlerなどのデバッグプロキシ
- Wiresharkなどのパケットキャプチャツール

---

というのが一般的な回答になると思いますが、個人的な想像としては・・・。

ログイン画面なのにIDとパスワードだけしかPOSTしないなんてのはセキュリティがーって言われそうなので、POSTするパラメータも足りてない気がします。`<input type="hidden">` とかHTMLに書かれていませんか？CookieにもセッションIDとか入ってそうです。

Comment: cookie に対応してないガラケーとかあるので、CookiJar を追加しないと（ガラケーと認識されて）動作対象外とエラーが帰ってくるのは多分にあるでしょうね。